# Dynamically create variables within range

Tags: variables, random, new-operator, dynamically-generated

In any programming language (like php, java, javascript etc) is it possible to dynamically create a changing number of variables in a loop, within a given name space?

for example, if I want to create N variables that have random numbers between 1 and 5, which are to be called random1, random2 ..  randomN, is it possible to do something like:

```
loop ( N ){<br>
  create variable randomN = random(1,5);<br>
}
```

Comment: An array or a list would be the standard approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you could use variable variables:

```
$N = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i != $N; ++$i) {
    ${"random$i"} = rand(1, 5);
}
```

In JavaScript, same thing:

```
var N = 5;
for (var i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    window['random' + i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
}
```

Though, I would recommend using a "container" to hold those variables, so that they're not created globally.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use $$, see [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
for ($n = 1; $n <= 5; $n++) {
    $varName = 'random' . $n;
    $$varName = rand(1, 5);
}

$vars = get_defined_vars();
var_dump($vars);
```